# Camera view range [Clip start and end not working]

Tags: camera

I have the same issue as some of users on Blender with the camera. 
[image: camera view set to 150Km]

So, my camera clip start is set to : 50 meters and my end is set to : 150000 meters. And, with this camera angle, we don't see the end of the square at the bottom of my building. I think the clip end is relatively correct to the the end of the square !

Comment: Can you share the dimensions of the building with us? If it's big, the solution is simply to increase the clipping distance in the camera settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Cameras have their own clipping, independent from the view.

Comment: Thanks ! You save my project :D