# Why does my camera clips no matter the "clip start" value I enter? whether I choose 0.0001 or 200 it doesn't matter

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, camera, geometry

Here's the problem for instance. The candy is the center is about 2cm large. But even then, the clipping should be ok with a clip start value of 0.00001. Even weirder, if I set the clip start variable to 200, nothing changes.

I just want the clipping to cease and my whole plane/candy to be visible. (yes the candy will also clip if I get slightly closer) :/

I'm really dumbfounded and not sure what to do. I'm asking for help, the users on this website have done miracles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: While you are looking through a camera, the camera's clip values are used instead. Change the camera's values in the Properties editor.

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155306/camera-view-range-clip-start-and-end-not-working